# JavaScript function remove <img> by src

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in JavaScript and I can't really figure it out:

I have to write a JavaScript script (no jQuery) to remove all the `<IMG>` tags that have the `src="file.jpg"` and adds round corners for all `<p>` and `<div>` tags having as background the image `"file.jpg"`.

I can't really work it out.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post a demo of your code so far and explain what failed?

Comment: i tried this way: http://pastebin.com/121PdsAM

Comment: You could do this with CSS instead of javascript. Add classes to the p and div tags and do something like this for the images `img[src="file.jpg"] {display: none}`

Comment: I could, but I have to use javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

If your desired file has different name, not `file.jpg` but for example `funnyImage.png` or something then change the image name (and `path` before it) if needed:

Remove the `<img>` tags with `file.jpg` as source:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(img => { 
    if(img.src === 'file.jpg') {
        img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
    }
});
```

Rounded corners:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p, div')).forEach(node => {
    if(node['background-image'] === 'file.jpg') {
        node.style['border-radius'] = '10px'; // for example 10px
    }
});
```

Or just (much more intelligent and efficient way):

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = 'p[background-image="file.jpg"], div[background-image="file.jpg"] { border-radius: 20px; }';
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Then you didn't provide all the information, because this will work if you want to remove `<img>` tags with `src='file.jpg'`.

Comment: Put the `<script>` tag *after* the body and it will work. Website is executed from top to bottom, you know. In the moment the Javascript is being executed there is still not `body` on the page. Or add `window.addEventListener('load', function() { /* here insert the JS code */ });` and it will automatically run when the page is loaded and all images are there already.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/frxbmrst/2/   . `\\` need to be escaped in string, otherwise you will get weird results.